# Task flows diagram for creating task analysis

Tags: task-flow

I am a Graphic designer learning User experience design. I need some help on creating Task flows diagram while working on task analysis. Is there any resource where I can learn how to create task flow diagrams. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know any in particular but read as much as you can - and think of what you're doing. What are the tasks? What are users doing (the tasks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone who approaches UX from a more scientific background/perspective, I encourage you to think about task analysis and task flow from first principles. By that I mean, work out what information you are trying to capture and work out the relationship between all the different pieces of information.

So if the purpose of you trying to undertake task analysis, and the output is a task flow diagram so that you can then work out the pages you need to design (that's my logical assumption), even without looking up any references these are probably the things that you need to document:

- Starting point for the task (and there might be more than one)
- End point for the task (again there might be more than one)
- Individual steps in the task (these might have dependencies on other tasks)
- Different people/process/systems involved in the task (these may relate to the dependencies of the steps involved in the task)
- Data produced or captured in the steps

Once you put all of those things down on paper (you may choose to use different symbols or icons to represent them), you can then begin to make the connections between the different elements more apparent by drawing connections and arranging them in a way that makes most sense to you. This might include:

- Whether the steps in the task progress in a linear fashion, or if there are multiple paths that can be taken to complete the task, in which case you might want to indicate what the ideal/frequent path is as opposed to alternate paths.
- Whether certain steps are conditional or dependent on other steps being completed, and whether those conditions or dependencies are internal or external to the current task.
- Whether the task is completed the same or different way by different types of users.

So for example, you can use some of the elements in the following images as a starting point and see how you can best tailor the diagram to suit your own particular case:

[image]

[image]

I would suggest not necessarily adding the chronological or experience scales since it over complicates the task analysis, but I do suggest that the diagram be structured in a way that is consistent and logical so that the visual representation reflects the actual complexity and relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you will want to break things down into use cases that represent a specific task the user wants to accomplish, then plot out all of the steps that might happen along the way to accomplishing it.

Here is an example of a use case for a single task with related task flow:
[image]

And another:
[image]

You might check out some of the online journals:

http://boxesandarrows.com/
http://www.uxmatters.com/
http://alistapart.com/topic/user-experience
http://www.uxbooth.com/
https://www.nngroup.com/

Here are a few articles that might be helpful:

http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2015/03/tools-for-mobile-ux-design-task-flows.php
http://boxesandarrows.com/views-and-forms-principles-of-task-flow-for-web-applications-part-1/
https://www.uxpin.com/studio/blog/creating-perfect-user-flows-for-smooth-ux/